# Does Terraform offer strong consistency with S3 and DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) offers [a few different backend types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/index.html) for saving its state. [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is probably the most popular one, but it only offers [eventual read-after-write consistency for overriding objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel). This means that when two people apply a terraform change at approx. the same time, they might create a resource twice or get errors because a resource was deleted in the meantime.

Does Terraform solve that using DynamoDB? WRITES in DynamoDB are strongly consistent. READS, by default, are only [eventually consistent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html), though.

So the question is whether there is strong consistency when working with S3 as a backend for Terraform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr: Using DynamoDB to lock state provides a guarantee of strongly consistent reads or at least erroring if the read is not consistent. Without state locking you have a chance of eventual consistency biting you but it's unlikely.

Terraform doesn't currently offer DynamoDB as an option for [remote state backends](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/index.html).

When using the [S3 backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) it does allow for using DynamoDB to lock the state so that multiple `apply` operations cannot happen concurrently. Because the lock is naively attempted as a put with a condition that that the lock doesn't already exist this gives you the strongly consistent action you need to make sure that it won't write twice (while also avoiding a race condition from making a read of the table followed by the write).

Because you can't run a plan/apply while a lock is in place this allows the first apply in a chain to complete before the second one is allowed to read the state. The lock table also holds an MD5 digest of the state file so if during plan time the state hasn't been updated it won't match the MD5 digest and so will fail hard with the following error:

```
Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
DynamoDB table to the following value: 9081e134e40219d67f4c63f4fef9c875
```

---

If, for some reason, you aren't using state locking then Terraform does read back the state from S3 to check that it's what it expects it is (and currently retries every 2 seconds for 10 seconds until they match or fails if that timeout is exceeded) but I think that it is still technically possible in an eventually consistent system for a read to show the update only for a second read to not show the update when it hits another node. In my experience this certainly happens in IAM which is a global service with eventual consistency, leading to much slower eventual consistency times.

All that said I have never seen any issues caused by the eventual consistency on the S3 buckets and would expect to see lots of orphaned resources because of things like that, particularly in a previous job where we were executing huge amounts of Terraform jobs concurrently and on a tight schedule.

If you wanted to be more certain of this you could probably test this by having Terraform create an object with a key of a UUID/timestamp that Terraform generates so that every apply will delete the old object and create a new one and then run that in a tight loop, checking the amount of objects in the bucket and exiting if you ever have 2 objects in the bucket.

Comment: I understand that DynamoDB is used for blocking. However, how does Terraform determine when to release the lock? Is there any guarantee S3 serves the updated state to all clients when they acquire a new lock? My concern is the following scenario: you get the lock, you upload changes, you release the lock. Then, when the second client gets the lock and gets the state from S3 they might still get the state before your update because of S3's eventual read-after-write consistency. Does Terraform come with some mechanism to ensure consistency?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I thought about the issue some more and I think it's technically possible for Terraform to check the state in S3 is what it should be and then for a second read from another Terraform operation to return the old state. However I have never seen this happen, even predating state locks and running a huge amount of Terraform jobs in cases where this failure condition would lead to "orphaned" resources where the state was not updated before the next run. If you were really, really scared of this then you should use something like GCS or Consul as a backend instead.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak funnily enough I was just hacking on something and manually edited a state file in S3 and my plan then failed because the MD5 digest of the state file didn't match the lock table entry. Removing the item from DDB allowed me to continue but that would have caught any issue around eventual consistency. I've updated my answer again with an explanation around that.